# How to use ldac on ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, codecs, 22.10, pipewire

system - Ubuntu 22.10

earphones - wf-1000xm4 (support ldac)

My system currently only show `msbc` and `mcvsd` as the audio codecs available. I have already installed `sudo apt install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` and restarted the system but to no help.

I read that ubuntu 22.10 (the one im using) is using `pipewire` instead of `pulseaudio` and it should have `ldac` support by default

However, if I run `pactl info` I get:

```
Server String: /run/user/1000/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 218
Tile Size: 65472
User Name: nitin
Host Name: bolt
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.58)
Server Version: 15.0.0
Default Sample Specification: float32le 2ch 48000Hz
Default Channel Map: front-left,front-right
Default Sink: bluez_output.F8_4E_17_8D_49_EC.1
Default Source: bluez_input.F8_4E_17_8D_49_EC.0
Cookie: 9bb8:c459
```

where I see both `pulsepudio` and `pipewire` (`PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.58)`) under the server tab. I am confused about how to enable pipewire (if I am not using it already) and use `ldac` codec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but I made LDAC work on Ubuntu 22.10.

[image]

No device was showing up in "Sounds", did a few things, this one made audio work with pipewire:

```
sudo systemctl --user restart pipewire
```